# How do I get the upper bound of a for loop in Python?

Tags: python, enumerate

I want to do the following in Python:

```
for index, value in enumerate(MyFunction()):
  logger.debug('Processing step %d of %d' % (index, len(MyFunction())
```

but that requires me to call MyFunction() during every iteration which I don't want. So of course I can do

```
mylist = MyFunction()
for index, value in enumerate(mylist):
  logger.debug('Processing step %d of %d' % (index, len(mylist)))
```

but that requires an unnecessary variable. Is there a more elegant way to refer to the maximum value of the loop index inside the for loop?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the second method. You want to create an object that you can then reuse and have a convenient name for it. That's exactly what variables are for. If anything I would create one more variable to keep the length of `mylist` so that you don't have to call `len` every iteration.

Comment: @RogerFan Creating another variables for the length seems excessive. Even if it has a performance benefit, it's a micro optimization and in most cases wouldn't pay back the costs of the extra variable (more code, more for the reader to keep in mind, the ever-so-slight possibility of a bug in that extra code, etc).

Comment: @delnan Of course it's a tiny thing and an individual preference, but I find `total_steps` easier to read than `len(mylist)`. It conveys meaning more directly, which makes the resulting code easier to understand. The latter seems to imply that `len(mylist)` might have changed each time you call it, while the former indicates that it is a constant value over the iterations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  In general, there may not be a maximum index, because you could do `for x in some_infinite_iterator()`.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I was thinking the number of iterations is fixed when you enter the loop - not so.

Comment: @markjan: It's only fixed if you iterate over a fixed-length sequence.  (Even then, you could still break out early.)

Answer (score 4):

The only way to know the upper bound is to first get the length of the sequence returned by `MyFunction()`.

Starting with your example, you can move the `len()` function outside the loop for efficiency:

```
mylist = MyFunction()
mylen = len(mylist)
for index, value in enumerate(mylist):
    logger.debug('Processing step %d of %d' % (index, mylen)))
```